# Loop through VLOOKUP Formula on multiple spreadsheets comparing to a variable spreadsheet names in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

I have two different workshooks. Workbook A and workbook B. I want to apply vlookup to see what values match between Workbook A and Workbook B on Sheets named "1" on both workbooks. then I want to loop and do the same for sheets named "2" and so on and so on. Not Much success with my macro it semi works. **NOTE SOME SHEETS DONT EXIST IN WORKBOOK B BUT EXIST IN WORKBOOK A** Anyone have any idea how to achieve this. I suspect it is to do with the w variable. Is there a way to count up on a string?

```
Sub y()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
     
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    sh.Activate
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 31 To LR
        For w = 1 To 41
            On Error Resume Next
            Cells(i, "E").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, "A"), Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsx").Worksheets(w).Range("A31:E1000"), 5, 0)
        Next w
    Next i
Next sh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To *"see what values match"* use [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub y()
   
    Dim wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, rng As Range, idx As Variant
         
    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbB = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsx")

    For Each wsA In wbA.Sheets
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsB = wbB.Sheets(wsA.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not wsB Is Nothing Then
            ' search range
            LR = wsB.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng = wsB.Range("A31:A" & LR)

            LR = wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 31 To LR
                idx = Application.Match(wsA.Cells(i, "A"), rng, 0)
                If IsError(idx) Then
                   ' do nothing
                Else
                    wsA.Cells(i, "E") = rng.Cells(idx, "E") ' column E
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```